# How to give a normal user permission to change root password

Tags: command-line, security, password

Please do not ask why, but is it possible to do it?

p/s: I know it's not a good thing, let's just say someone from the top management who is computer illiterate want some sort of *control* over the server.

Comment: Don't we have an 'evil' tag? :P

Comment: Can't resist.  Why?

Comment: giving a user the right to change the root password is the same as giving them full root access, so why bother giving them "only" password-changing access?

Comment: He probably heard the story about the San Francisco network admin. It's not that stupid, if he can be trusted to use this power only in such an emergency.

Comment: @starblue, what story of the San Francisco network admin?

Comment: This question is pretty meaningless without a why. It's much easier to create a SUID trojan shell and hide it someplace that looks reasonable but boring (this also works for hiding contraband from your parents, aurorius (without the SUID bit, which doesn't do much for contraband)).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Childs

Comment: @hop: I could imagine the following situation where there is a difference. What if someone else who has access to root changes root's password? Then, if you knew the old password, you don't have the access anymore. But if you still can change the password as another user, it's "ok". Of course, if the password change was intentional, the changer could also disable this user to a degree wished. Also, there are often other ways to overcome loosing the root's password, such booting another OS and mounting the partition, and changing the password then. Back to the Q a 2nd root (eg,toor) might work.

Comment: @imz: you are confusing authorization with authentication. if the boss' authentication is not done via the root password, his authorization to do root stuff is not depending on him knowing the root password either.

Comment: @hop: yes, I agree with you. In my mind, I simplified "giving them full root access" to "giving them the password to authenticate themsleves as root" when I read your comment. If understood in the precise way, your words are not something that makes my comment relevant.

Comment: There are two elephants in the room.   (1) The smaller one is a question: How is the system configured?  Is it configured to use both `sudo` and `su`?  If `su` is disabled, what good does the root password do?  And, if you don’t have `sudo` enabled, that knocks out the best answer.   (2) There’s a big, obvious difference between “giving them full root access” and this.  With “full root access”, the person can do anything, any time, possibly without being detected.  With this “change the password” hack, it will (probably) be obvious if they do it.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (This gets back to elephant #1 — if everybody else uses `sudo`, will they notice if the root password has been changed?  You could add a tripwire so all the regular sysadmins get notified when the manager does this.)  It’s like having a locked door with a breakable window — you *allow* emergency access, but you make it obvious that the access has been taken.

Comment: Please explain "some sort of control "! You can have as many super-users as you like; they do not depend on the name `root` but on the UID `0`. Let the slaughter begin ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't do that... you can either give them root's password or you could execute `sudo passwd root` (this assumes that sudo is set to use the users password or no password, and that passwd is a command that sudo has authorized to be run by that user).

Answer (score 6):

`sudo` is the swiss-army knife of customized permissions.  You could ask the user 
 to run

```
sudo /usr/bin/passwd root
```

To see how this might be enabled, here's a related example from the sudoers(5) manpage.

```
pete           HPPA = /usr/bin/passwd [A-Za-z]*, !/usr/bin/passwd root

The user pete is allowed to change anyone's password except for root on the 
HPPA machines.  Note that this assumes passwd(1) does not take multiple 
usernames on the command line.
```

You'll have to invert the logic to achieve your ends, of course.  So, you would execute the `visudo`, and add a line like

```
user ALL = /usr/bin/passwd root
```

to `/etc/sudoers`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can add this line to the sudoer file (using `visudo`), replacing `phunehehe` with the username.

```
phunehehe localhost = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/passwd
```

I don't know if that breaks your condition of a "normal user", though, because after that he/she has so much power.

EDIT: as per xenoterracide's comment :)

Comment: I don't know why you'd think he'd need this. He didn't ask you to make it passwordless. why reduce the security of the system more than necessary if you're doing anyting like this it should be `user localhost = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/passwd` which would limit the security accesss to just that.

Answer (score 3):

Can't he use run level 1 to change root password?

What I have in mind is

1. Set grub password so that not every user can change the run level at boot time.
2. This password is given to the normal user who might need to change root password in future.
3. Now if needs arise to change the root password, he can modify grub parameters at boot time. Press 'a', give grub password and then give 1, so that machine boots into run level 1.
4. Once in run level 1, he can change root password.

The obvious disadvantage of this procedure is that machine has to be rebooted and while its in run level 1, it will be offline.

Kindly mention the flaws that you find in this procedure.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't trust the owner of the root account then there's probably no way to prevent that root user from removing this special permission.  If you do trust the root user then just ask him for the current password.

Comment: What does “the owner of the root account” mean?  Are you suggesting that Ralph Oot might be given the username “root” (like in the current TV commercial, where the robot goes to a coffee shop, and the barista labels his cup “Rob Ott”)? (Believe it or not, I wrote this comment *before* I took a good look at your identicon image.)

Comment: But you and I seem to be interpreting this question in totally different ways. You seem to believe that it’s about protecting the system against a rogue sysadmin who might change the root password and not tell anybody the new password. I believe that it’s about giving a manager immediate emergency access to root privilege at off-hours, without needing to bother anybody immediately.

Comment: @g-man the only control you have is trust. If you trust your admins, they can set up a system that provides enough access control, like sharing the root password or adding a certain user to sudoers. But if you don't trust your admins there's nothing you can do to stop them from messing up your system. Hence just sharing the root password. 12 years later I would add "design your network with disaster recovery including losing access to certain accounts or systems" but ultimately there are some keys which need to be shared.

Answer (score 3):

If your system used [pam_tcb (tcb - the alternative to /etc/shadow)](http://www.openwall.com/tcb/) (and hence there were users' password files per user), you could also achieve what you want by managing file permissions and groups (say, add this user to the group that you make own the password file for root).

In this case, I don't see any principal differences in the results as compared to the `sudo`-solution (if you are ready to trust `sudo`, of course), because you are anyway giving away the highest privilege to that user.

But in other cases, `pam_tcb` gives more flexibility and security: first, you ought not to trust `sudo` and `passwd` in that they won't let the user exploit the privileges in an unwanted way; second, less privileges must be given to users to achieve certain similar configurations (and no setUID-root programs are needed at all) -- see, e.g., the question for a similar thing: [Reset [another] user's password without root](https://serverfault.com/questions/271630/reset-users-password-without-root/271968#271968)
.

Answer (score 1):

If you trust that user so that he has permission to change root password, it should be safe to give him the current root password in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If that user has sudo access then sudo passwd root dose the work. If we don't have sudo access then it'll prompt for the password again. If we know the password the work can be done.

Answer (score 0):

#Log in as root

```
 Login: root
```

#Modify your /etc/sudoers file to allow your 'NON-ROOT USERNAME' to run 'passwd' to change the root password
#FIRST Change 'NON-ROOT USERNAME' to whatever your actual username is

```
echo 'Cmnd_Alias   PW      = /usr/bin/passwd [A-z]*' >> /etc/sudoers

echo 'NON-ROOT USERNAME    ALL     = (ALL) NOPASSWD: PW' >> /etc/sudoers
```

#Log in as your NON-ROOT USERNAME

```
Login: stan
```

#Make an alias for 'passwd' that will be 'sudo passwd'

```
echo 'alias passwd="sudo passwd"' >> .bashrc
```

#Log out

```
logout
```

#Log in as your NON-ROOT USERNAME

```
Login: stan
```

#Change roots password

```
passwd root
```

Comment: (1) This is wordy and unclear. (2) More importantly, it more-or-less duplicates a couple of old answers without explaining the differences.  Is your answer better than the others? If so, why? (3) Please don’t tell people to edit their `/etc/sudoers` file with `echo` and `>>`.